# Why my check box isn't updated after click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use React Hooks to update the list of items. When users click on the check-box, the app should render the items which have been selected as purchased.

I could log the event of the `handPurchase()` and the state is correct, however, I can't make the function render the latest state.

With class, I can do:

```js
const handlePurchase() {
  // ...
  this.setState(updatedGroceries);
}

this.state.groceries.map(//...render list
```

This is the code:

```js
export default function CheckboxList() {
    let initialGroceries = [
        {
            id: "one",
            text: "Apple",
            purchased: false
        },
        {
            id: "two",
            text: "Banana",
            purchased: false
        }
    ];
    const [groceries, setGroceries] = useState(initialGroceries);

    const handlePurchase = (id: string) => () => {
        groceries.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.id === id) {
                item.purchased = true;
            }
        });
        setGroceries(groceries);   
    }

    return (
      <List>
        {groceries.map((item) => {
          const labelId = `checkbox-list-label-${item.id}`;

          return (
            <ListItem key={item.id} role={undefined} dense button onClick={handlePurchase(item.id)}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Checkbox
                  checked={item.purchased}
                  inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={item.text} />
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </List>
    );
}
```

Also, if I do this:

```js
const updatedGroceries = groceries.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.id === id) {
                item.purchased = true;
            }
        });
        setGroceries(updatedGroceries);
```

I get this error:

> Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ id: string; text: string; purchased: boolean; }[]>'.  TS2345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `forEach` does not return anything as you might expect. I guess you would like to update with `setGroceries` the `purchased` property on the elements where the provided `id` is equals to the current one to `true`. So you need to return an array for example with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). From the documentation:

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

I guess the following can work for you:

```
const updatedGroceries = groceries.map((item) => {
  if (item.id === id) {
    item.purchased = true;
  }

  return item;
});

setGroceries(updatedGroceries);
```

In your code you were assigning to `updatedGroceries` the `forEach` result which is `undefined` because it does not return anything, find [here in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. That does work. I've actually tried it but I probably missed something so it didn't work.